# Macro for making numbered lists in vim?

Tags: vim, macros

Often times it seems I have a list of items, and I need to add numbers in front of them.  For example:

```
Item one
Item two
Item three
```

Which should be:

```
1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three
```

In vim, I can press `I` in edit mode, insert "1.", hit escape.  Then I go to the next line, press `.`, and then `^A` to increment the number.  This seems hugely inefficient... how would I make a macro so that I can go to the next line, and insert a number at the beginning which is one greater than the line before?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can easily record a macro to do it.

First insert `1.` at the start of the first line (there are a couple of spaces after the `1.` but you can't see them).

Go to the start of the second line and go into record mode with `qa`.

Press the following key sequence:

```
i                         # insert mode
<ctrl-Y><ctrl-Y><ctrl-Y>  # copy the first few characters from the line above  
<ESC>                     # back to normal mode
|                         # go back to the start of the line
<ctrl-A>                  # increment the number
j                         # down to the next line
q                         # stop recording
```

Now you can play back the recording with `@a` (the first time; for subsequent times, you can do `@@` to repeat the last-executed macro) and it will add a new incremented number to the start of each line.

Comment: Use `3@a` to to perform the macro 3 times

Comment: I'd go for `k^yWjP^<ctrl-a>j` instead. The text may not be at the start of the line, and more important your macro won't work after the tenth line.

Comment: Spot on, @Luc - precisely how I had it myself except I tacked on ^ to the end so that it positioned the cursor at the start of the line when done. No functional difference due to the ^ at the start, just felt a bit neater.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: <CTRL-A> will go to the last digit. I suggest `^` afterwards.

Comment: @LucHermitte It would be better if you could explain what each of the character does here. Thanks.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh, You can call `:h` on each part of the macro to know what it does. It'll work well here. `k` -> previous line, `^` -> start of the line, `yW` -> do I need to present this one ?, `j` -> move cursor to the next line, `P` -> you should know what it does if you are a vim user, `^`-> start of the line again, `<C-A>` is the one that does the job here : it increments the number under the cursor, and `j`-> next line again.

Answer (score 15):

Select your lines in visual mode with: `V`, then type:

```
:'<,'>s/^\s*\zs/\=(line('.') - line("'<")+1).'. '
```

Which is easy to put in a command:

```
command! -nargs=0 -range=% Number <line1>,<line2>s/^\s*\zs/\=(line('.') - <line1>+1).'. '
```

Comment: I like the repeatability of this. For single lines it's great. Unfortunately, for *my* purposes, when inserting numbering I tend to be doing in reStructuredText, and so need essentially `}` functionality - but due to the way it's doing line counting, merely replacing `^` with `\n\n` wouldn't cut it. Pity, otherwise it would have entered my `.vimrc`.  Good code, anyway, I wasn't aware of `\=()` - and I can't find it in the vim help!

Comment: You can use any function you'd like, like for instance a function that keeps a count for itself. In that case, you may have to play with a command that encapsulates the "loop", e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim/1809780#1809780 . Otherwise, see `:h sub-replace-\=`

Comment: This is a nice, facile way to created a simple numbered list.  I added the following entry to my .vimrc; to use it, make your Visual selection then press your "leader" key (mine is remapped to the space bar) + "n"; i.e. <space>n.  vnoremap <leader>n :s/^\s*\zs/\=(line('.') - line("'<")+1).'. '<CR>

Comment: @VictoriaStuart. Prefer `:xnoremap` here in order to not mess the select mode -- which is the one used by most snippet plugins.

Comment: The corresponding `:UnNumberLines` is much simpler: `command! -nargs=0 -range=% UnNumberLines <line1>,<line2>s/\d\+\. //g`

Answer (score 14):

Here's an easy way, without recording a macro:

1. Make a blockwise, visual selection on the first character of each list item:

   ```
   ^<C-V>2j
   ```
2. Insert a `0.`  at the beginning of these lines:

   ```
   I0. <Esc>
   ```
3. Re-select the visual selection (which is now all of the `0`s) with `gv` and increment them as a sequence `g<C-A>`:

   ```
   gvg<C-A>
   ```

The entire sequence: `^<C-V>2jI0. <Esc>gvg<C-A>`.

[A recording of the process in action](https://asciinema.org/a/330383).

Comment: This is the best solution. Didn't even know about `gv` or `g<C-a>`, and now that I've learned them they can be used in other situations too.

Comment: I agree. It's brief, precise and I learned more about the g operator.

Comment: Incredible! Find help on  `gv`  with `:help gv`. Find help on  `g<C-A>`  with `:help v_g_CTRL-A`.

Answer (score 7):

There are also some plugins for doing this type of work if you have to do it on occasion:

http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=670

Comment: Cannot agree more, a plugin dedicated for that task is far better than a home made macro, and this because creating series is a task that you will have more than once.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the 'record' feature.
It is an easy way to record macros in Vim.

See :help record

In normal mode 'qa' to start recording what you type in the 'a' register
Type the necessary command to insert a number at the beginning of line, copy it to next line and use CTRL-A to increase its value.
'q' to end the recording
then '@a' to replay the macro stored in register 'a'
('@@' repeat the last macro).

And you can do things like '20@a' to do it twenty times in a row.

It is pretty handy to repeat text modification.

Depending of the cases, it is easier or harder to use than a regexp.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's not a macro solution, but at least it's easy.

**add numbers to all lines**

It's possible to use `:%!nl -ba` or `:%!cat -n` commands which will add line numbers to all the lines.

<sup>On Windows, you've to have Cygwin/MSYS/SUA installed</sup>.

**add numbers to selected lines**

To add numbers only for selected lines, please select them in visual mode (<kbd>v</kbd> and cursors), then when finished - execute the command: `:%!nl` (ignore blank lines) or `:%!cat -n` (blank lines included).

**formatting**

To remove extra spaces, select them in visual block (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) and remove them (<kbd>x</kbd>).

To add some characters (`.`, `:`, `)`) after the numbers, select them in visual block (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), then append the character (<kbd>A</kbd>, type the character, then finish with <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: To add some characters (`.`) you can use `:'<,'>normal a.` on selected lines. As the selection was done before, repeat it with `gv`.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a number at the start of the block of text eg.

`1. Item One`

Enter the vim normal mode command as follows:

```
qb^yW+P^<Ctrl-A>q
```

This means:

```
qb       # start recording macro 'b'
^        # move to start of text on the line
yW       # 'yank' or copy a word including the ending whitespace.
+        # move one line down to the start of the next line
P        # place text ahead of the cursor
^        # move to start of text
<Ctrl-A> # increment text
q        # Finish recording macro
```

What this allows you to do is replay the macro across the last line of numbered list as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is some time later and I think it is time to upgrade this answer, at least for neovim users.
Here I wrote a lua function you can bind to Enter and it will work on any imaginable type of list, such as

```
1. foo
 1.99-> bar
```

and after pressing enter, this line will be added:

```
 1.100->
```

all using this function

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i','<Enter>','v:lua.enter_or_list()', {expr = true})

function _G.enter_or_list()
  local line = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(0, vim.fn.line('.') - 1, -1, false)[1]:match('^%s*[^%a%s]+')
  if not line then
    return '\r'
  else
    local start, finish = line:find('[^%a%s]*%d')
    local main = line:sub(start,finish)
    local suffix = line:sub(finish+1)
    return table.concat({
      '\r',
      main,
      vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('<Esc><C-a>a', true, true, true),
      suffix,
      ' '
    })
  end
end
```

for vim users, I have a little simpler, but a little less capable keybinding:

```
imap <silent> <S-Enter> <CR><Esc>kk<End>Ev<Home>yjpk<End>e<C-a><End>a<Space>
```

I hope this will be useful to other people as well, as it is very convenient.
Cheers