# How do I renumber a list in vim?

Tags: regex, math, vim

I wrote a section of a webpage that had the following bit...

```
<span id="item01">   some first presented text</span>
<span id="item02">   some other text, presented second</span>
<span id="item03">   more text</span>
....
<span id="item15">  last bit of text.</span>
```

I then realized that it should have been numbered from 14 to 0, not 1 to 15.  (Yes, bad design on my part, not planning out the JavaScript first.)

Question.  Is there an easy way in vim to do math on the numbers in a regular expression?  What I would like to do is a search on the text "item[00-99]", and have it return the text "item(15-original number)"

The search seems easy enough -- /item([0-9][0-9])/
(parentheses to put the found numbers into a buffer), but is it even possible to do math on this?
[Macro for making numbered lists in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224410/macro-for-making-numbered-lists-in-vim) gives a way to number something from scratch, but I'm looking for a renumbering method.

Comment: Seems like the sort of thing you should be generating programmatically from an array, maybe, instead of hard-coding in the HTML? Just a thought.

Comment: Like I said, bad design on my part :)  What I am doing is generating a fixed-sized text grid (with variable text in each cell).  I originally had the (0,0) coordinates in the upper left corner, but the math for the grid has (0,0) in the lower left corner.  I wanted to be able to just access each cell as needed, rather than output the entire table on each update.

Answer (score 12):

```
:%s/item\zs\d\+/\=15 - submatch(0)/
```

will do what you want.
Breaking it down:

- `item\zs\d\+`: match numbers after `item` (the `\zs` indicates the beginning of the match)
- `\=`: indicate that the replace is an expression
- `15 - submatch(0)`: returns 15 minus the number matched

Comment: Given the use of `\zs`, you can leave off the parentheses in the regex and just reference `submatch(0)` instead of `submatch(1)` in the replacement.

Comment: I suggest to use `g` command to only apply substitution to the lines containing `item`: `:%g/item/s/\d\+/\=15 - submatch(0)/`. It allows to get rid of `\zs` (even if some may argue that it is less precise than the original answer).

Answer (score 7):

Another interesting way is to use `g<CTRL-a>` (`:help v_g_CTRL-A` for more information)

Start from

```
<span id="item01">   some first presented text</span>
<span id="item02">   some other text, presented second</span>
<span id="item03">   more text</span>
....
<span id="item15">  last bit of text.</span>
```

Use visual block mode to reset all numbers to `00`:

- `<CTRL-V>` select all numbers
- `r0` replace all numbers with zeros

You should be seen:

```
<span id="item00">   some first presented text</span>
<span id="item00">   some other text, presented second</span>
<span id="item00">   more text</span>
....
<span id="item00">  last bit of text.</span>
```

Now restore your block select with `gv` or just select all lines with `V` and press `g<CTRL+a>`

```
<span id="item01">   some first presented text</span>
<span id="item02">   some other text, presented second</span>
<span id="item03">   more text</span>
....
<span id="item015">  last bit of text.</span>
```

Unfortunately one last clean up is needed here. As you can see, all two digit numbers get `0` in front. Use visual block mode `<CTRL+v>` again to select and remove unwanted zeros.

```
<span id="item01">   some first presented text</span>
<span id="item02">   some other text, presented second</span>
<span id="item03">   more text</span>
....
<span id="item15">  last bit of text.</span>
```

Now you are done :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have vim with perl (many distributions have that by default), you can
use `:perldo` commands to do it. (@Marth solution is better)

```
:perldo s/(?<=item)(\d+)/15 - $1/e
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [VisIncr plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670).  It adds support for increasing / decreasing columns of numbers, dates, and day names, in various formats.  Quite handy when you have to deal with these kind of things.