# vi, condition in vimrc

Tags: vim, file-type

I am trying to personalize my `~/.vimrc` file.

Here is what I want: when the file name opened with vi is `titi45.tex`, and when I press `<space>` in normal mode, I want that the command `make toto45`
is executed. And if the file opened with vi is called `titi65.tex`, I want that
`make toto65` is executed, and so on.

I tried to use a command

```
au FileType tex nmap <space> :w<CR>:!make<CR><CR>
```

in my `.vimrc` but I don't know how to match the file name and use the number.

Can you help me?

Mathieu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `:make %<`. BTW why don't you compile within vim? Avoid `:!make`. Prefer `:make`, and check the help related to the quickfix mode (`:h quickfix`).

Your mapping would then be:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <space> :update<cr>:make %<<cr>
```

(the `<buffer>` part is very important, it makes sure your mapping won't leak to other filetypes; the other are not critical here, but good practices)

---

EDIT: Sorry I missed the exact requirement.

Then, you'll have to transform the target name. You'll to play with `substitute()` and `:exe`. But your substitution won't be a simple substitution. It looks like a rotating substitution. Solutions for this kind of substitution have been described over there: [How do I substitute from a list of strings in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim)
And IIIRC, there exist a plugin that does similar things.

In your case, I guess I would use a dictionary to define how names are substituted:

```
let k_subs = { 'toto': 'titi', 'titi': 'toto' }
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <space> :update<cr>:exe 'make '.substitute(expand('%'), join(keys(k_subs), '\|'), '\=k_subs[submatch(0)]', '')cr>
```

NB: I haven't tested it.

If you want to get rid of the extension, it'd better be done in `expand()` argument.

Comment: I have several reasons why i don't want to compile within vim. Be carefull! with the file titi87.tex, i want to execute `make toto87.tex` (and not `make titi87`). And i do NOT want to execute anything with the file tutu87.tex (for exemple). So your mapping is not suitable...

Answer (score 0):

Hum...
finally i use an additionnal script

```
#!/bin/bash

maRegex='source_(enonce|corrige)([0-9]+)$'

if [[ "${1}" =~ $maRegex ]]
then
        commande="make enonce${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
else
        commande="make plouf"
fi

echo commande de compilation lancée: $commande
$commande
```

This script in launched by vimrc.