# Is it possible to mark the n-th occurrence of a pattern with n in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

Say I have a text like the following.

> The man is walking, and the man is eating.

How should I use substitution to convert it to the following?

> The man 1 is walking, and the man 2 is eating.

I know I can use `:%s/\<man\>//gn` to count the number of occurrences of the word `man` and I know `/\%(\(pattern\).\{-}\)\{n - 1}\zs\1` can find the n-th occurrence of pattern. But how do I mark the n-th occurrence?

Any help is sincerely appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to have a non-pure function that counts occurrences, and use the result of that function.

```
" untested
let s:count = 0
function! Count()
    let s:count += 1
    return s:count
endfunction

:%s/man\zs/\=' '.Count()/
```

Comment: Just a small addition. If you don't want to add this to your vim script then most likely you want to use global variables i.e. `let g:count = 0` or at least buffer vars: `let b:count = 0`. About variables namespace you can read in `:help internal-variables`

Comment: Maya this should be modified as `:%s/man\zs\ze/\=' '.Count()/`. Thanks, this is of great help to me!

Comment: @awllower. I wanted to use `\zs` actually, but in the rush, I used the other one. Thanks!

Comment: @DawidGrabowski. I usually provide command and full functions for this kind of exercises, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim/1809780#1809780. This time, I went for the quick and dirty approach

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a macro.
First, search for the pattern, like `/man /e`.

Let's create a variable for count, like `:let cnt=1`.

Now, let's clear the `a` register.

Start recording by pressing `qa`.

Press `n`.

Press `i`, then, Ctrl+R type `=`. Type `cnt`. Value of count is inserted there. 
Then, type `:let cnt=cnt+1`.

Press Escape.

Press `q` to stop the register.

Now, type `:%s/man //gn` to get number of occurrences.

Now, you know the number of occurences, say 10. Then, you will press `10@a`.
All the occurrences will be appended with a number, which is incremented for every occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for this surprisingly simple macro approach.