# Is there a command to search and replace in Vim with different substitutions for each occurrence?

Tags: vim

I have this Cucumber script for testing a website where I want to populate the `"fum-portlet"` with the names of a bunch of different portlets

```
Then I should see element "fum-chart-portlet"

Then I should see element "fum-chart-portlet"

Then I should see element "fum-chart-portlet"

Then I should see element "fum-chart-portlet"
```

like `"fum-chart-portlet", "inflow-chart-portlet", "fees-chart-portlet"`

Vim only has the option of replacing all occurrences with one substitution as far as I know.

Comment: What is the logic? As in, how do you know what the substitutions should be?

Comment: @Enlico Basically I want to replace each occurrence of "fum-chart-portlet" with a different portlet name from a list of portlet names.

Comment: Is the list in the same file? Please, provide the sufficient info!

Comment: Very similar Q/A here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809571/how-do-i-substitute-from-a-list-of-strings-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace with variable strings, you'll have to specify them. Depending on how your files look, there may be a number of ways to do so.

The easiest way to replace them would be to use *blockwise Visual mode*. Format your list of replacement strings as you would like them to appear in the output (do this in a *scratch buffer* if you hesitate to change your source file).

In your example, you have one empty line between lines, like this:

```
"fum-chart-portlet"

"inflow-chart-portlet"

"fees-chart-portlet"
```

Place your cursor on the first character, press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to enter blockwise Visual mode and select to the last character. Press `y` to yank the selection.

In your target buffer, place the cursor on the beginning of the first `"fum-chart-portlet"`, press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and select to the bottom. Press `p` to replace the selected block with the one yanked earlier.

See `:help visual-block` for more information.

Another idea would be to search and replace incrementally. You can go to your replacement list and `yi"` the first string. Then search for `/"\zsfum-chart-portlet\ze"` (the `\zs` and `\ze` are used to exclude the quotes from the match, see `:help /\zs`), press `gn` to visual-select the *next* occurrence of it and `p` the string over the selection. Repeat until your done. See `:help v_gn` for reference.

In fact, I'd go with the simple manual approach of replacing just the first part by searching for `/"\zsfum\ze-chart-portlet"` and then `gncinflow<Esc>gncfees<Esc>`.